# Search duplicate in table slow perfomance

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find the duplicated records available inside the `fixtures` table so I wrote this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM fixtures f
INNER JOIN (SELECT *
           FROM fixtures s
           GROUP BY s.match_id
           HAVING COUNT(player_id) > 1) dup
       ON m.match_id = dup.match_id;
```

but the query is really slow and there are only 1000 records in the table. This is the records available:

```
player_id | match_id  | team_id
  19014       2506172    12573
  19014       2506172    12573
  19015       2506172    12573
  19016       2506172    12573
  19016       2506172    12573
  19016       2506172    12573
```

the query should return as duplicated the 19016 and  19014 player, what I did wrong?

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view) and 
 
 [**How do I obtain a Query Execution Plan?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

Comment: Define what is duplicated? All fields equal? Same player on a match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for dupes across all three columns, i don't see why you need a join.

```
SELECT player_id, match_id, team_id, count(*) 
FROM fixtures
GROUP BY player_id, match_id, team_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: ok, yours seems to work, but if I want remove only the duplicates? could you please show me how?

Comment: @Spartaok Are there any other columns on the table, or just those 3? Any ID or value to differentiate those duplicate records from each other?

Comment: no the table contains only these columns: `player_id, match_id, team_id` the production table have something like 6.820.213 records and a lot of records duplicated..

Comment: @Spartaok Post a new question or do some research on it. SO posts are for only 1 question each, and I don't want to provide code in comments.

Comment: could you take a look at that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53396170/how-to-safely-remove-only-duplicated-rows/53397144?noredirect=1#comment93669882_53397144 maybe you know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do `aggregation` ? :

```
SELECT s.player_id, s.match_id, s.team_id
FROM fixtures s
GROUP BY s.player_id, s.match_id, s.team_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

However if i re-look at question i would suggests :

```
SELECT s.player_id
FROM fixtures s
GROUP BY s.player_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your db browser limited the resultset.(1000 row)

```
SELECT f2.*
FROM fixtures f
JOIN fixtures f2 on (f.match_id = f2.match_id and f.player_id<f2.player_id)
```

It will be faster a don't list duplicates with lowest playerid.
But all duplicated match id is in the result.