# How to safely remove only duplicated rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tables that contains 6.820.483 and between these rows there a lot of duplicates, I discovered that running this query:

```
SELECT player_id, match_id, team_id, count(*) 
FROM fixtures
GROUP BY player_id, match_id, team_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

structure example:

```
player_id | match_id  | team_id
  19014       2506172    12573
  19014       2506172    12573
  19015       2506172    12573
  19016       2506172    12573
  19016       2506172    12573
  19016       2506172    12573
```

how can I safely remove only the duplicates? In the example above the table should looks like:

```
player_id | match_id  | team_id
  19014       2506172    12573
  19015       2506172    12573
  19016       2506172    12573
```

table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `swp`.`fixtures` (
  `player_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `match_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `team_id` INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `player_id_idx` (`player_id` ASC),
  INDEX `match_id_idx` (`match_id` ASC),
  INDEX `FK_team_fixtures_id_idx` (`team_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_player_fixtures_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`player_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`player` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_match_fixtures_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`match_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`match` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_team_fixtures_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`)
    REFERENCES `swp`.`team` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: What do you mean by remove?  Do you want to delete them from the table, or just select only unique values?

Comment: @WillardSolutions I need to delete them because are duplicated check the example for understand

Comment: Is there a primary key on the `fixtures` table?

Comment: Does your table have some PK that uniquely identifies a record?

Comment: @WillardSolutions nope, the table contains FK of records available in other tables

Comment: Could you add the complete table descripton?

Comment: And are there any other columns on this table?  If you start randomly deleting rows, is there other data in the rows that you will lose?

Comment: @RobertKock check table description

Comment: Just to be safe on your side, I think you need to just create a table and populate it with DISTINCT values from that table.... if you're satisfied with it, you can delete the previous table and rename the new table you created...

Comment: guys I just need to know how can I remove the duplicate records on that table thanks

Comment: I would refer you to this article. It doesn't directly address your problem but you can delete from fixtures where the @rownum > min(@rownum) in the select query.  This will get rid of all duplicates.  In fact another method would be to alter the table, add a rownum, and then delete from table for rownum>min(rownum).  Then alter the table to drop the column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a MySQL expect but you could try this (if you're sure no new records will be inserted in the meantime):

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_fixtures
(
  player_id INT NOT NULL,
  match_id  INT NOT NULL,
  team_id   INT NOT NULL
);

SELECT DISTINCT
       player_id,
       match_id,
       team_id
  INTO tmp_fixtures
  FROM fixtures;

TRUNCATE TABLE fixtures;
```

In order to make sure no duplicated records are created anymore, you could do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE fixtures ADD PRIMARY KEY (player_id, match_id, team_id);
```

After this, repopulate the table and clean up:

```
INSERT INTO fixtures (player_id, match_id, team_id)
  SELECT player_id,
         match_id,
         team_id
  FROM   tmp_fixtures;

DROP TABLE tmp_fixtures;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. When you do not use a PK, most DBMS would fail deleting a row in case of ambiguity. Moving old data to a new table **which would use PKs** is the only safe way to step out of this mess.

Comment: Right idea, wrong database.  You should be using `create table as`.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Robert and forpas both provided much better answers, but technically I believe this could be done without creating a new table (at least in MSSQL). I've attempted to translate into MySQL.  Again I would likely never do it this way, especally on large data sets, but it was an interesting exercise.

As with all solutions, if you do attempt this backup your table first.

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0

WHILE @i < 6820483
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM f
  FROM (
      SELECT *
      FROM fixtures
      WHERE player_id IN (SELECT player_id FROM fixtures GROUP BY player_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
      LIMIT 1
  ) f

  SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Also as pointed out by the other answers, you will likely want to create a `Primary Key` to prevent this in the future.

Comment: but why robert solution give me the error error: undeclared tmp_fixtures?

Comment: @Spartaok I'm not sure, maybe SELECT INTO isn't valid in MySQL. His syntax would work in MSSQL. If that isn't allowed in MySQL you could always create the table first and do `INSERT INTO tmp_fixtures SELECT DISTINCT...`

Answer (score 1):

There is no other solution but backup distinct rows of the table in a temporary table and restore it afterwards just like @Robert Kock proposed, but: 
duplicates can appear again just like before.  
So prior to restoring the table run this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE swp.fixtures ADD PRIMARY KEY(player_id, match_id, team_id);
```

to add a multi-column primary key so the problem will not appear again. 
**Edit1** 
From: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html

> MySQL Server doesn't support the SELECT ... INTO TABLE Sybase SQL
>   extension. Instead, MySQL Server supports the INSERT INTO ... SELECT
>   standard SQL syntax, which is basically the same thing. See Section
>   13.2.6.1, “INSERT ... SELECT Syntax”. For example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
    SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
    FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

**Edit2** (after Gordon Linoff's suggestion)
So the whole code should be:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_fixtures AS 
    SELECT DISTINCT player_id, match_id, team_id FROM fixtures;

TRUNCATE TABLE fixtures;

ALTER TABLE fixtures ADD PRIMARY KEY(player_id, match_id, team_id);

INSERT INTO fixtures (player_id, match_id, team_id)
    SELECT player_id, match_id, team_id FROM tmp_fixtures;

DROP TABLE tmp_fixtures;
```

**Use with caution and only if you have a backup of your data.**

Comment: the solution propose by robert return an error could you check that'

Comment: Ah right you are. It was text copied from the source. My bad.